# hdfs_connect("localhost",9000) leads to "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration" error

Tags: hadoop, julia

I want to use HDFS.jl in julia. But, every time I input the command
`hdfs_connect("localhost",9000)` the error occurs:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:323)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:268) 
Can't construct instance of class org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration  
ERROR: hdfs connect failed
 in hdfs_connect at /home/gxx/.julia/v0.3/HDFS/src/hdfs_dfs.jl:35
 in hdfs_connect at /home/gxx/.julia/v0.3/HDFS/src/hdfs_dfs.jl:30
```

My hadoop version is 1.2.1, and my classpath is:

```
export HADOOP_HOME=/home/gxx/usr/hadoop/hadoop-1.2.1
export CLASSPATH=.:$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/rt.jar:$JAVA_HOME/lib/dt.jar:$JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar:$HADOOP_HOME/*.jar:$HADOOP_HOME/lib/*.jar:$HADOOP_HOME/hadoop-core-1.2.1.jar
```

[This is the link of HDFS.jl](https://github.com/tanmaykm/HDFS.jl)

How to fix it?